# Should I use publishDate or datePublished for schema.org Review markup?

Tags: schema.org

I'm using schema.org’s `Review` and I would like to know if I should use `publishDate` or `datePublished` properties.

According to the doc (http://schema.org/Review), it seems to be `datePublished` but in the example they use `publishDate`.

Comment: It's `datePublished`. There should be no doubt about that. (FYI, there are also `dateModified` and `dateCreated`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would lean towards 'datePublished', as I can't find 'publishDate' in their [full documentation](http://schema.org/docs/full.html).

Comment: Yep, just for the record: `publishDate` is no longer mentioned in the example on schema.org.